# Truncating part of a postgres table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am running Postgres version 10.01

```
psql -V
psql (PostgreSQL) 10.5
```

I have a table `mytable` with about 250 million rows - my objective is to create a new table `newtable` and copy about half of the `mytable` into `newtable` (`SELECT * WHERE time > '2019-01-01` ), then to delete the records I copied from `mytable`

Of course, I want to keep all indices in `mytable`

What is the most efficient command to do this in `psql` ? `TRUNCATE TABLE` is efficient but will remove all rows. `DELETE` would probably take a lot of time and prevent inserts from happening (INSERTS are scheduled every 10 mins)

Any suggestions would be helpful

Comment: Insert all your rows into the new table and then do INNER JOIN deletes

Comment: Unrelated, but: `psql -V` prints the version of the command line utility `psql`. It's not the version of the Postgres **server**. That can reliably only obtained by running `select version();`

Comment: `DELETE` will not prevent inserts

Comment: If you had created a partitioned table, it would have been very simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to proceed in two steps.

First, copy the rows to the new table. You can use a CREATE..AS SELECT statement (but you will need to recreate indexes and other objects such as constraints manually on the new table after that).

```
CREATE TABLE  new_table
AS SELECT * FROM old_table WHERE time > '2019-01-01
```

Then, delete records from the old table. It looks like an efficient way would be to JOIN with the new table, using the DELETE...USING syntax. Assuming that you have a primary key called id :

```
DELETE FROM old_table o
USING new_table n
WHERE n.id = o.id
```

(Be sure to create an indice on id in the new table before running this).

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to delete rows couldn't you just treat your delete as a transaction. Unless your insert is dependent on the existing data in the table, there should be no blocking.